# How to disable the close button in GTK?

Tags: python, gtk, client, pygtk, odoo

I have created a One Time Password mechanism in OpenERP 6.0.3's GTK client. After login the GTK client shows a window to enter the One Time Password as below.

[image: One Time Password Window]

Now I want to disable the close button at the top left of the window. How can I do that? I am using python and the code to create the window is:

**EDIT**

```
class sms_auth(gtk.Dialog):

    def run_thread(self):
        code=self.textbox_code.get_text()
        self.result = rpc.session.rpc_exec_auth('/object', 'execute', 'res.users', 'check_code', code)
        return self.result

    def run(self):
        self.show_all()
        res = super(sms_auth, self).run()
        result = None
        if res == gtk.RESPONSE_ACCEPT:
            result = self.run_thread()

        self.destroy()
        return result

    def hide(*args):
        window.hide()
        return gtk.TRUE

    def __init__(self, parent, response):
        # To use cancel butto add gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_REJECT,
        gtk.Dialog.__init__(
            self, 'Sms Authentication', parent,
            gtk.DIALOG_MODAL | gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
            (gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
        )
        label = gtk.Label("Please enter sms code :")
        self.parent_widget = parent
        self.response = False
        self.db_login_response = response
        self.connect('delete_event', hide)

        self.textbox_code = gtk.Entry()
        label.set_alignment(0,0)

        table = gtk.Table(1, 7)
        table.set_homogeneous(False)
        table.set_col_spacings(40)
        table.attach(label, 0, 6, 0, 1, ypadding=4)
        table.attach(self.textbox_code, 5, 6, 0, 1, ypadding=4)

        self.vbox.pack_start(table,False, False, 0)
```

Comment: You have an answer already so I'll just make a comment: Preventing window close/hide is almost always a bad idea. People make mistakes and your app should allow them to cancel any actions that possibly can be cancelled. Also: the button can't be disabled visually, it'll look like a working button but won't do what people expect...

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
def hide(self, *args):
    window.hide()
    return gtk.TRUE


self.window.connect('delete_event', self.hide)
```

Note: Refer [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/29853-gtk-pygtk-how-remove-close-button-top-right-corner-dialog-window)

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk


class DialogExample(gtk.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent,
            gtk.DIALOG_MODAL | gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
            (gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
        )
        self.set_default_size(150, 100)
        label = gtk.Label("This is a dialog to display additional information")
        box = self.get_content_area()
        box.add(label)
        self.show_all()
        self.connect('delete-event', self.delete_event)

    def delete_event(self, widget, event=None):
        print "Here"
        return True


def main():
    # rest in gtk_main and wait for the fun to begin!
    gtk.main()
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DialogExample()
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But I am getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./openerp-client.py", line 135, in <module>
    win.sig_login()
  File "/home/user/workspace/Sms_authentication/client/bin/modules/gui/main.py", line 1035, in sig_login
    sms_auth_obj = sms_auth(self.window, res)
  File "/home/user/workspace/Sms/client/bin/modules/gui/main.py", line 1655, in __init__
    self.window.connect('delete_event', hide)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'

Comment: where to add the code `self.connect('delete_event', hide)` in the init method? I have updated the code, please check.

Comment: Try `self.connect('delete_event', self.hide)`. Because you are using `gtk.Dialog`

Comment: [gtk.True deprecated](http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2005-March/009750.html)