# Making a Gtk.Window not deletable

Tags: window, gtk

I need a Gtk.Window that is not deletable. So if the user clicks the "close" button (every generic window has  "close", "minimize" and "maximize" buttons) the Gtk.Window shouldn't close.

I tried `Gtk.Window.set_deletable(False)`, but it doesn't work. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Please rephrase.

Comment: Do you really want to disable the *close* button? Or do you really want to hide the *close* button entirely? Or show a pop-up when the *close* button is pressed (e.g., ask to save progress, etc.)?

Comment: I want to disable it or showing it off, i don't want the user has a chance to close the window

Comment: Does this answer your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21178694/369450

Comment: It seems working, thank you. I would add an edit to that answer: [gtk.True is the same as True](http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2005-March/009750.html) (True/False have been added to Python since 2.2.3 /2.3). Please rewrite your comment as an answer, so i can close the question